# IE issue with css attribute position and z-index inside table

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, position, z-index

I've an IE issue,

There's a structure, where I want `td` has css attribute `z-index:1`, `position:relative`. It appears how it has to be appear in other browser than `IE`. Do IE(7,8) support this attribute in table ?

Comment: Can you show us what is "behave normally" and/or  "behave anormally"? Without any example, it's rather hard to understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

(http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position)

So you can't blame IE this time =p

Can't you apply these rules on a child of table-cell element?